# How does a pending GitHub Actions job behave when more than one commit happened subsequently and it gets canceled?

Tags: github-actions

Currently our workflow is triggered on push to be deployed:

```
concurrency: prod

on:
    push:

jobs:
    test-deploy:
        environment: prod
```

The `test-deploy` job needs to be approved manually and is therefore in a pending state, as job #1. What happens if I make two more commits b and c, which don't trigger a new deployment (due to the pending #1) and then cancel job #1? Will it trigger a new deployment job for commit b or one for the latest commit c?

Comment: If you push two more commits separately, it should actually start 2 new workflow runs. In that case, you'll have 3 workflow runs pending and waiting for manual approval. I would suggest using [concurrency](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency#example-using-concurrency-and-the-default-behavior) at the workflow level to guarantee previous "on going" runs are cancelled when a new commit is made.

Comment: Hi @GuiFalourd thanks, i forgot to mention that I am using concurrency. Do you know what happens in that case?

Comment: Ok, I added an official answer with what I understand you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you push two more commits separately, it should actually start 2 new workflow runs. In that case, you'll have 3 workflow runs pending and waiting for manual approval.

To avoid this behavior, I suggest using [concurrency](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency#example-using-concurrency-and-the-default-behavior) at the workflow level, to guarantee previous "on going" runs are cancelled when a new commit is pushed to the branch.

That way, only the latest run will need to be approved manually for the deploy to occur.

Your workflow would therefore look like this:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - your-branch-that-trigger-deploy

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  deploy:
    environment: prod
    steps:
      ...
```